# How to run queue worker on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, cron

My Laravel application has a [queued event listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#queued-event-listeners) and I have also set up the cronjob to run [`schedule:run`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling) every minute.

But I don't know how I can run the `php artisan queue:worker` command persistently in the background. I found [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/free-queue-solution-for-shared-hosting) where it was the most voted approach:

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --daemon')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```

However, on a [different thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/database-queue-on-shared-hosting) some people complained that the above-mentioned command creates multiple queue worker.

How can I safely run a queue worker?

Comment: there is cron job menu on shared hosting. just set the command there

Comment: You have to be more specific. Which command should I run as a cron job? `schedule:run` or `queue:work`? I have already mentioned in the question that I am running `schedule:run`. I just need to run `queue:work` in such a way so that a) it doesn't die b) no multiple instances of the process is created

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.7, there's a new queue command to stop working when empty:

`php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty`

As this is mostly just for emails or few small jobs, I put it on a cronjob to run every minute. This isn't really a solution for more than 100 jobs per minute I'd say, but works for my emails. This will run about 5 seconds every minute just to send emails, depending on how many emails or how big the job.

#### Steps

1. Create new command: `php artisan make:command SendContactEmails`
2. In `SendContactEmails.php`, change: `protected $signature = 'emails:work';`
3. In the `handle()` method, add:

```php
return $this->call('queue:work', [
    '--queue' => 'emails', // remove this if queue is default
    '--stop-when-empty' => null,
]);
```

4. Schedule your command every minute:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('emails:work')->everyMinute();
    // you can add ->withoutOverlapping(); if you think it won't finish in 1 minute
}
```

5. Update your cronjobs:

```php
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/project/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

---

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

> #### Processing All Queued Jobs & Then Exiting
>
> The `--stop-when-empty` option may be used to instruct the worker to process all jobs and then exit gracefully. This option can be useful when working Laravel queues within a Docker container if you wish to shutdown the container after the queue is empty:

```php
php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty
```

Comment: You can also use `$schedule->command('emails:work')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();`

Comment: Yes Ali, like stated in number 4. :)

Comment: For me by just adding a cronjob like `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/project/artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty > /dev/null 2>&1` works fine. Is it a good practice @emotality

Comment: @Ishaan That will work yes. Only downside is that it is not in your project code. So you have to setup the schedule cronjob and this cronjob every time. But I guess you only setup a server once soo.. Should be fine?

Answer (score 1):

are you using cpanel?

you can set in the `Scheduler` or `Cron Jobs` menu.
and set the command in there

Comment: I have a cron job added. Here is the output of `crontab -l`: `SHELL="/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell"
* * * * * cd /home/oeit/oe && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`. However it's not affecting at all. Queues are not cleared from the `jobs` table. Here's what I am doing in the `schedule()` method of `Kernel.php`: `$schedule->command('queue:restart');
 $schedule->command('queue:work');`

Answer (score 1):

You can set a schedule task like this

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```