# Laravel Queue queue:work running in background in Shared hosting(CPanel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-queue

In my project, I've made a simple newsletter system where I want to send an email to all subscribers. But the problem I faced in production ***(Cpanel hosting)*** I have to run `laravel queue:work` command in terminal. Can anyone tell me how to handle `queue:work` in background in CPanel hosting...
can anyone tell me how to handle this problem?
For sending the mail I'm using the cpanel mail smtp not using any other third party like mailchimp or mailgun etc...

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273132/how-to-run-queue-worker-on-shared-hosting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141652/running-laravel-queuework-on-a-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**find crob job tab into your cpanel then set the cron job **
like

- daily
- after 5minutes or whatever you want

make a job to handle the user news letters like

```
php artisan make:job UserNewsLetters
```

and then make a email

```
php artisan make:mail NewsLetterEmail
```

make a view into mail/newsletter
access the mailabel into your job set cron job path to your project folder like this /usr/local/bin/php /home/hosting_user/public_html/artisan queue:work  or you can utilize laravel console commands https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

[please check this image and set cron job not run commandline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4shJk.png)

add this command into your cron task with full php path

```
 php /path/to/laravel/artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty
```

to check php path run this in commandline

```
which php
```

**cron task have these options to run your job**
1-once per minute (mean job only run once in one minute so once per minute mean it will run 60 times in One Hour)
2-Every day mean once in 24hr
3- weekly job run once in a week

you can also make console commands for schedule your task and laravel have clear documentation [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224674/discussion-on-answer-by-tameemahmad-shahzad-laravel-queue-queuework-running-in).